# onTouchEvent how to get curret view under finger

Tags: android

this is my code

```
public class Main extends Activity {  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        LinearLayout rLinear=new LinearLayout(this);  
        rLinear.setId(200);  

        for (int c=0;c<5;c++)  
        {  
            ImageView imEdit = new ImageView(this);  
            imEdit.setId(300+c);  
            imEdit.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);  
            imEdit.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(36, 36));  

            rLinear.addView(imEdit);
        }
    }  
}
```

Okay, I have this code, I'm adding 5 ImageView to an linear layout at runtime, so far so good, but what i would like to do is, when the user slide his finger over one of them, i would like to change the image, so my question would be, how can i know what's the current imageview under the user finger.??

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This is what I've used to find a first non-ViewGroup view under finger. It is recursive and uses getGlobalVisibleRect

```
private View findViewAtPosition(View parent, int x, int y) {
    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)parent;
        for (int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            View viewAtPosition = findViewAtPosition(child, x, y);
            if (viewAtPosition != null) {
                return viewAtPosition;
            }
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        parent.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
        if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
            return parent;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.i(TAG, "View under finger: " + findViewAtPosition(getRootView(), (int)ev.getRawX(), (int)ev.getRawY()));
}
```

Comment: you might start from `viewGroup.getChildCount() -1` to `0` to get the most top view under touch

Answer (score 3):

Apply

```
    rLinear.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        String eventName = "";

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)v;

        for(int i =0; i< layout.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View view = layout.getChildAt(i);


            Rect outRect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());

            if(outRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
            {
                                  Log.d("", view.getId());
            }
        }
    }});
```

ps: this code button is a mess

Comment: This code will find only views of one level of the current view, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Call performClick() when handle onTouchEvent to dispatch click event to target view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set different graphics for when the Images are touched you can use StateListDrawables and set the ImageView source to the xml file which describes which image to show in which states

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

e.g.
<selector android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item state_pressed="true" drawable="@drawable/redbutton">
<item state_focused="true" drawable="@drawable/redbutton">
<item drawable="@drawable/bluebutton">
</selector>

Comment: I copied the answer from previous post: ok thanks for your answer, but I think it won't work for me (i didn't test it yet, but I'm positive it won't) because what i need if changing picture while the user is dragging his finger, during the movement, so let's say that i've 5 ImageView and I start dragging my finger from first one and without release the finger I touched all of them, then release the finger, how can i change every ImageView pic (during the movement)??... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Layout inflater.. have a look on codes given below...

```
LinearLayout lin_layt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_layout);

final FrameLayout fl[]=new FrameLayout[size];
View ResultList=new View(Result.this);
             ResultList=layoutInflater.inflate(getResources().getLayout(R.layout.result_list), null);
             fl[i] = new FrameLayout(this);
             fl[i] = (FrameLayout) ResultList.findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout_middle);

//                              
                fl[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch(event.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            fl[x].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.middlestripselect);
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            fl[x].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.middlestrip);




                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                });



             lin_layt.addView(ResultList);
```

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, but I think it won't work for me (i didn't test it yet, but I'm positive it won't) because what i need if changing picture while the user is dragging his finger, during the movement, so let's say that i've 5 ImageView and I start dragging my finger from first one and without release the finger I touched all of them, then release the finger, how can i change every ImageView pic (during the movement)??... Thanks.